# Link component works first time button is pressed, but not subsequent times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Link executes on the first button press, but not on subsequent tries.  Doesn't operate properly until the page is reloaded.

I have the following:

```
<Link to="/dashboard">
    <button type="button" className="pPlus" onClick={() => saveFunction(state)}>Purchase Offset Credits</button>
</Link>
```

It works and refreshes /dashboard the first time I press the button, but subsequent times /dashboard isn't refreshed even though state variables have changed. "saveFunction(state)" is correctly executed each time.

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Is `/dashboard` the active route before the first click?

Comment: Yes it is. The link is to refresh that route with new changes in the state variables.

Comment: Sorry, actually the button does a post route to the database with new state data and then the desire is to read the database again and refresh all of the users data on the page